# min function don't work in mysql and wordpress plugin

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I tested below code in my sql and it worked:

```
 SELECT min(`user_registered`) as mindt FROM `wpf_users'
```

but when i use it in php it don't show any thing:

```
<?php 
    global $wpdb;
    $min_year=$wpdb->get_results("SELECT min(`user_registered`) as mindate FROM {$wpdb->prefix}users"); 
    echo($min_year->mindate)."hh"; 
?>
```

where is the problem!?

Comment: can you vardump `$min_year` variable? what it gives you??

Comment: Whatever library you are using (you don't say) must have functions to fetch error messages. Whatever, it's very unlikely that a method that accepts SQL code and it's called get_result**s** returns a single scalar value. I'm sure you're using the library wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this article](http://www.wphub.com/working-with-database-tables-plugins-part-2/)<sup>1</sup>, you need to use `$wpdb->get_row();` instead of `$wpdb->get_results();`:

```
global $wpdb;
$min_year=$wpdb->get_row("SELECT min(`user_registered`) as mindate FROM {$wpdb->prefix}users"); 
echo($min_year->mindate)."hh";
```

Another possible way could be *(although I'm not sure it will work)*:

```
$min_year=$wpdb->get_results("SELECT min(`user_registered`) as mindate FROM {$wpdb->prefix}users")[0];
```

<sup>1</sup>: <sub>I'm not a Wordpress expert.</sub>